# ConventionProfile is obsolete useIConventionPack Instead

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I just updated my Mongo-C# driver from 1.6.1 to 1.8.1 and what I realized is that they have made a lot of functionality obsolete. one of the error that I am seeing due to deprecation is following:

> Convention Profile has been obsolete, Please replace it with
>   IConventionsPack.

Now, the problem is that there is not much documentation about IConeventionPack at all or how to use it. I am posting a small code snippet can anyone please suggest on how to handle this using IConventionPack?

```
var conventions = new ConventionProfile();
           conventions.SetIgnoreIfNullConvention(new AlwaysIgnoreIfNullConvention());
           BsonClassMap.RegisterConventions(conventions, t => true);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it turned out that there is not library supplied implementation of IConventionPack. I had to handwrite an implementation of IConventionPack. Here is the code sample:

```
public class OpusOneConvention : IConventionPack
{
    public IEnumerable<IConvention> Conventions
    {
        get { return new List<IConvention> { new IgnoreIfNullConvention(true) }; }
    }
}
```

Followed by:

```
var conventions = new OpusOneConvention();
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreIfNull", conventions, t => true);
```

So basically, all of your Conventions will go as an IEnumerable and then ConventionRegistry will be responsible for registering them.

thanks.

Note: As of version 1.8.1.20, you can use the ConventionPack as follows:

```
var conventions = new ConventionPack();
conventions.Add(new IgnoreIfNullConvention(true));
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreIfNull", conventions, x => true);
```

Comment: As of 1.8.1.20 there is a library supplied implementation here: http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/28ac3635-dfe6-41bf-d29f-8fcd9c27715a.htm